# How do I create a database with database name as variable using Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I am learning how to work with Python and MySQL. I wanted to know how can I create a database with it's name as variable using python. I have tried this but it does not work at all. I have used this method in insert query so thought it might work in this too.

```
db_query=('''CREATE DATABASE VALUES(?)''')           
VALUES=email2
my_cursor.execute(db_query,VALUES)
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: [CREATE DATABASE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-database.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database name is not an expression that can be computed in MySQL, it has to be literal, so you can't use a placeholder or function call there.

If the database name is in a Python variable, use string formatting to substitute it.

```
email2 = 'desired_db_name`
db_query = f'CREATE DATABASE `{email2}`'
my_cursor.execute(db_query)
mydb.commit()
```

If the DB name comes from user input, make sure you validate it carefully first.

Comment: From where did you get this glorious bit of knowledge?  For example, the [MySQL CREATE DATABASE documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-database.html) doesn't seem to say it **must** be literal.

Comment: Anything that isn't documented to be an expression must be a literal, I believe. I don't think it's stated explicitly in the documentation of each statement.